# How can I allow DNS through the Mac OS X Server 10.6 Firewall?

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I'd like to use the default Firewall manager app to setup a firewall, but adding an entry for "DNS, port 53" does not seem to do the trick. DNS traffic is blocked when the firewall is on.

Looking in /etc/ipfilter/ipfw.conf.apple I can see that adding that entry created a line for exposing TCP traffic on port 53, but not UDP.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to resort to manual ipfw.conf setup?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Turns out there is a more advanced management interface for the firewall, located in the Server Admin tool. The "Services" tab therein contains all the options I needed (specifically, checking 'DNS - inbound queries').

Thanks to http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1573022&seqNum=2 for the good write-up!